# TypeError: this.$store.dipatch is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am learning Vue and currently struggling with this error.

```
TypeError: this.$store.dipatch is not a function
```

I have made `store.js` file and trying to access the actions from a `vue` file.

I have searched alot about the same but couldn't find any solution. Any idea what might be the cause ?

Comment: try dispatch instead of dipatch..

Comment: Have you included vuex and made vue use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo.
Try this:

```
this.$store.dispatch('yourActionName')
```

Read More in the following link:
Vuex

- [Vuex actions](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/actions.html)